# google workspace authentication withouth the windows pop up just with api key or client id or seceret

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I need to authenticate the users api for the google workspace without the popup window open and click on my gmail account is there any way to do that just with the api key or client and secret.

Comment: Edit your question to state what you are trying to do clearly. In some cases, you can use a service account with Domain Wide Delegation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible because the OAuth consent screen is a native security feature for API access to certain scopes (Specially [restricted](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) scopes). This will always happen when there is a user interaction [Consent Screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent).

That said, the only way to avoid that may be using a [service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726) depending on what you are trying to do.